Find the confidence interval of ratio of variance with unknown distribution but known mean
From the previous question, I'm going to assume that for a random sample $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ and $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$, that $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} \xrightarrow{D} N(0,1)$ by Central Limit Theorem and $\frac{(\bar{X}-\mu)^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}} \xrightarrow{D} \chi_{(1)}^2$. I was thinking of using these theorems to bring it to F-distribution, but I'm not sure if you can do such a thing, since it is only converges in distribution and not the actual distribution. But otherwise, I have no idea how to find it.

Your question is vague, Albert.  First, what is the "previous question" to which you refer?  Second, could you please explain what you mean by "bring it to F-distribution"?
